# Entity Framework 4 and SQL Server 2008 R2 Change Data Capture Not Playing Nicely Together

Tags: silverlight-4.0, entity-framework-4, wcf-ria-services, sql-server-2008-r2, domainservices

When I try to use these two features together, I get a compilation error on my model (note, I've renamed the entity for my _CT table "ContentHistory" and my SL4 Unit Test project is called "DomainServices.UnitTest":

```
Error 39 Property 'DomainServices.Web.ContentHistory.C___seqval' is marked as a key
property and is of Type 'System.Byte[]', which is not a supported type for a key member.
DomainServices.UnitTests
```

Has anyone here gotten CDC and EF4 to play nicely together?

Comment: Okay, so here's the way this breaks down. The CDC tables in the database have no primary keys. As a result, EF4 infers the key. It's not making good choices. For that matter, I'm not sure what a good choice is since binary(10) and varbinary(128) are not valid types for key columns in EF4.

Comment: You're just trying to use EF to *read* the CDC tables, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here's what I've done to work around this issue. I made sure that every table that I want to enable CDC on has a `LastModified` column of type `datetime`. Then, I added a key (from an EF point of view) consisting of the `LastModified` column and the `__$operation` column. I figure this is "probably unique" (which is somewhat frightening, but probably okay). My reasoning is that the `LastModified` is accurate to about 3ms, so the only time that I'll (realistically) get 2 rows in my CDC table with the same `LastModified` is on an update; but, on an update those two rows will have different `__$operation` values (a 3 and a 4). So, compounding those together makes at least a modicum of sense for a key. I am not a big fan of this, and wish that EF4 would support tables with no keys. If anyone has a suggestion, please please let me know.

Comment: To reiterate, I don't like this answer. It's just what I'm doing to "get by." If there's a better answer out there, someone please chime in :)